# Upload data to server repeatedly

Tags: android, service, scheduled-tasks

I need to upload data to the server repeatedly (say after every 10 minutes). The application will check in the local SQLite DB if there's any unsynced data and will upload it.

If I call an `AsyncTask` from a `Handler` repeatedly, will it work even when the app is paused (user navigates to another application)?

How can a `Service` be used to do this (as service can be run in the background)? Should I use `Service` or `IntentService`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` can run after the calling app is destroyed, however, if it calls `onPostExecute()` it will crash the app if this method updates the UI.  Handlers will also continue to run.  However, the JVM process may be killed off at any time.  AsyncTask is only supposed to be used for short tasks lasting a few seconds.

A `Service` is not married to an activity and can outlive it should the app be destroyed.  This is where you should be updating your server.

A good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: What about `ScheduledExecutorService` ?

Comment: @AbdulFatir - I'm unfamiliar with that.

Answer (score 0):

If I call an AsyncTask from a Handler repeatedly, will it work even when the app is paused (user navigates to another application)?

[When Android kills an app, can a function be stopped halfway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611893/when-android-kills-an-app-can-a-function-be-stopped-halfway/14611934#14611934)

"AsyncTask may continue running but may or may not to be fully functional"

How can a Service be used to do this (as service can be run in the background)? Should I use Service or IntentService?

I guess it is better to use service to do this. (i am not so sure anyway)

[What is the difference between an IntentService and a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771323/what-is-the-difference-between-an-intentservice-and-a-service)